# Using class methods and variables after deleting class

Tags: python

So I was messing around in the Python IDLE Shell today and I noticed something.
I had a class like so:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I created an instance of the class and printed out the name:

```
name1 = Name("Cameron")
print(name1)
```

Then I deleted the class:

```
del Name
```

But then realized that I could still use 'name1' like nothing ever happened:

```
# still returns 'Cameron'
print(name1)
```

Can somebody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Reference counting?  Though you delete the local name for your Class declaration, the instance still contains a reference so there's something still in memory that prevents the GC from removing it completely?

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Reference counting is CPython-specific. The more general answer is that as long as there's a reference to the object, Python won't delete it—whether you're using a refcounted implementation like CPython or a different kind of GC like PyPy or Jython. As explained in user2357112's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`del` doesn't mean "destroy this thing". It means "unassign this variable". Other references to the object the variable referred to are unaffected, and as long as the object is reachable through some chain of references, it won't be destroyed.

When you execute

```
del Name
```

the `Name` variable is gone, but the `Name` class the variable used to refer to is still around. `name1` has a reference to its type, so it will continue to work fine.

Comment: +1. In particular, `name1.__class__` is that reference.

Comment: @cli_hlt: No, the `Name` class is not gone. The name `Name` is gone, but the class it referred to is also referred to by `name1.__class__`, which isn't, so the class can't be collected. You can even still construct new instances—e.g., `name2 = name1.__class__("cli_hlt")`.

Comment: @abarnert Allright - I am not that deep into how things are implemented there. In theory it could be gone, but when name1.__class__ still is to reference the class it belongs to, you are of course right. Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @cli_hlt: The OP was asking why it's _not_ gone, which means that "in theory it could be gone" doesn't matter; in practice, it's not, and there's a good reason why it's not, as this answer (and pswaminathan's answer) explains.

Comment: I was also confused because I can't make another instance of that class. That's what made me believe the class was gone in the first place. `name2 = Name("Robert")` throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

The `del` statement doesn't actually *delete* the object. It removes the reference to the object. In this case, when you instantiate `name1 = Name("Cameron")`, you are making another reference to the object. When you use `del Name`, it just removes one of them.

Comment: Refcounting is a red herring here. There's nothing about the Python language that requires refcounting; it's just how CPython happens to implement its garbage collector. The key is that as long as there's a live reference to an object, it can't be collected. Whether the implementation knows that because the refcount is 1 (as in CPython) or because it found a reference in its last sweep (as in PyPy) or because the underlying VM's magic says it's still alive (as in Jython) isn't important; what matters is that the reference exists.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't think my comment through fully. Will fix that now.